# How to Round up timestamp to number of Days?

Tags: sql, date, datediff

```
PreparedStatement psnmt=con.prepareStatement("SELECT (?)-(?) as DiffDate FROM dual");
psnmt.setTimestamp(1,ctenderdate);
psnmt.setTimestamp(2,btenderdate);
ResultSet resrt=psnmt.executeQuery();
if(!resrt.next())
{
     out.println("No Records Found");
}
else
{
  do
     {
        datediff=resrt.getString("DiffDate");
     }
  while(resrt.next()); 
  System.out.println("the no of days Difference"+datediff);
              
}
```

> ctenderdate=2015-06-27 00:00:00.0
>
> btenderdate=2015-06-29 00:00:00.0
>
> datediff=1 10:18:51.940000000
>
> Expected datediff=2

How to round it off datediff to number of days

Comment: Check out [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp) please.

Comment: @Alp ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis its giving this error

Comment: try removing the ( )'s [parenthesizes] from your SQL statement.

Comment: "DATEDIFF": invalid identifier

Comment: Assuming your DB is oracle, why don't you get the SQL statement right first and then use the same SQL statement in your code. To do so, you use Oracle's SQL command line tool (SQL*Plus or something) and ensure above statement works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT

**Subtract TIMESTAMP values**

If we really want to subtract two `TIMESTAMP` values, then we have to work with the `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` datatype that's returned. The easiest way to work with that is to use the `EXTRACT` function.

If want to return integer number of days (emulating the `CEIL` function) then we could test whether any part of the time (`HOUR`, `MINUTE`, `SECOND`) was non-zero. If they are all zero, we can use just the `DAY` portion. Otherwise, we have to add 1 to the `DAY` portion, and return that.

For example:

```
  SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM diff.idts) 
         + CASE 
             WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR   FROM diff.idts) > 0 
               OR EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM diff.idts) > 0
               OR EXTRACT(SECOND FROM diff.idts) > 0
             THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END
         AS days_diff
    FROM ( SELECT ? - ? AS idts FROM dual ) diff
```

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

For Oracle database, you can perform this operation in the database:

```
SELECT CEIL(TO_DATE(?,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.F')-TO_DATE(?,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.F'))
  FROM dual
```

This assumes the bind parameters are passed as strings, in format that matches the format model specified in the TO_DATE function, for example:

```
  '2015-06-27 14:45:21.0'
```

(I'm assuming Oracle because of the use of the `dual` table, and because you are using subtraction operation between two dates. You would need a different statement for a different database.)

To unpack that expression a little bit...

The Oracle `TO_DATE` function converts a character string into an Oracle `DATE` value.  The second argument is the format model, specifies that format of the first argument.

A subtraction operation between two `DATE` values returns the difference as a number of days (integer days plus fractional days.)

The `CEIL` function rounds a non-integer value up to the next higher integer.

**FOLLOWUP**

**Q:** how to use it with timestamp?

**A:** A subtraction of two `TIMESTAMP` values gets returned as an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` datatype. And I'd prefer to avoid working with that.

In Oracle, when we do a subtraction of two `DATE` values, we get a decimal number. That's much easier to work with.

And in terms of "rounding" up a difference in days, I'm fine with disregarding fractional seconds.

If I had to pass in `TIMESTAMP` values, I would convert them to `DATE` values. The expressions above are already expecting string values, so I would just replace the **`?`** with

```
 TO_CHAR(?,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

If I had a requirement to pass in `TIMESTAMP` datatype, and return integer days difference rounded up, I would use a query like this:

```
 SELECT CEIL( TO_DATE(TO_CHAR( ? ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
            - TO_DATE(TO_CHAR( ? ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
        ) AS days_diff
  FROM dual
```

Comment: how to use it with timestamp?

Comment: I would convert the `TIMESTAMP` to `DATE`, so I could get a decimal number from subtraction. Personally, I'd avoid returning the `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2459688?start=0). There are answers for results in hours or minutes. What you are looking for should be similar.

My bad. I should not post just-a-link-answers. What you can do, as described there is:

```
SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE) - TO_DATE ('10/20/2012', 'mm/dd/yyyy') FROM DUAL;
```

Notice the following details:

> ENDDATE - STARTDATE will give you a number that corresponds to the
>   number of days between the two dates.
>
> If you want the result in hours, multiply by 24; if minutes, multiply
>   by 24*60 and so forth.
>
> You can also convert the result to an INTERVAL. There are two type of
>   intervals: NUMTODSINTERVAL(ENDDATE - STARTDATE, 'DAY') or
>   NUMTOYMINTERVAL(ENDDATE - STARTDATE, 'DAY')

Comment: i want to round up it to next number of days

Comment: If you read the posts on the page, for which I sent you the link, you will see that someone has a comment: _To add to what Ranit said, ENDDATE - STARTDATE will give you a number that corresponds to the number of days between the two dates._